# windows run script with local user account from administrator powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have written a script which will do some stuffs on my application and that application running as local user `app1user`. So I need to run that script from Administrator account and call that script with `runas /user:app1user`, but it prompts for the user `app1user` password.

Is there anyway that we can overcome this and run that script as `app1user` without using password through powershell.

Also am tried to calling that script from Evlevated powershell window only.

Comment: You *Might* be able to accomplish this with user impersonation, [This Link](http://www.powershellatoms.com/powershell-101/how-to-impersonate-someone-in-powershell/) can hopefully help get you started.

Comment: There is no way to you can do this but you can overcome by storing credentials

Answer (score 2):

In powershell you can use **-Verb RunAs**. Now you can use from cmd also and you can directly use it from Powershell also.

**CMD:**

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"C:\Temp\`\"; & \`\".\Script.ps1\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"
```

**Powershell with new session (you can pass *NoNewWindow* also):**

```
Start-Process powershell "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command `"cd \`"C:\Temp\`"; & \`".\Script.ps1\`"`"" -Verb RunAs
```

**Next Alternative is using Dot Net :**

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);

# Get the security principal for the administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

# Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole)){"Its in elevated mode"}
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: @Randip Thanks. But how can I run the command as local user `app1user` from administrator.

Comment: See if you want to run with a specific user then you have to pass the password which you don't want it seems.

Comment: Yes I want to run with a specific local user from Administrator

Comment: BUt in that case you have to pass the password @Karthi1234.. There is no alternative way. Or you have to store the password in a file as an encrypted string and from there you have to take input. Thats just another way..